# PHP plugin to calculate spam assassin spam score?

Tags: php, spam

I have spam assassin on my hosting server. Is there any way to plug into it and calculate the spam score of an e-mail, before it is sent out? Preferably not invoking spam assassin directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even question being very old, someone might find it useful.

[Pure PHP client for Spamassassin](https://github.com/templateria/php-spamassassin)

Answer (score 4):

There is a free service available now that allows you to calculate your SpamAssassin score through a RESTful API:

http://spamcheck.postmarkapp.com/doc