# How to check the spam score of an email subject

Tags: php, email, spam

I'm looking for a PHP API/class/method to calculate the spam score of an email's subject for use on a marketing website (as in, the spam score is calculated while *building* an email, not on *receiving* an email). I've seen similar products like SpamAssassin but wondered if there's anything more basic seeing as only the subject score is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Dunno, spam score calculation is very complicated (check against dictionnaries with mutated versions ...). You should check out dokuwiki's wordblock feature's source code it may be useful : http://www.dokuwiki.org/blacklist

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417590/php-plugin-to-calculate-spam-assassin-spam-score

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interface with SpamAssassin.  There is some code here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130119010823/http://ppadron.blog.br/2010/05/04/php-api-to-spamassassin-spamd-protocol/

Comment: Love to see that content, but the link is broken now :(

Comment: @CaptainHypertext Fixed.  Archive.org had it.  https://web.archive.org/web/20130119010823/http://ppadron.blog.br/2010/05/04/php-api-to-spamassassin-spamd-protocol/

Answer (score 0):

spam score of an email is not only calculated by the subject, but is the sum of hundreds of classifiers. checking your spam emails subjectg wont get the mail through.

if you really want to check your mail before sending programatically, generate a dummy mail with your subject and run it through a local spamassassin installation via command line.